# AutoFill Right Index Match with column variation

Tags: excel, vba

The below code applies a formula  every 7th row, and i would like it to AutoFill Right until the last column -1 (Because the last column has a SUM).

```
Sub test5()

'Prv. Cheg

Dim ShtPlan     As Worksheet
Dim ActSht      As Worksheet
Dim lastRow     As Long
Dim sheetName   As String
Dim lookupFrom  As String
Dim myRange     As String
Dim myRange2    As String
Dim i           As Long


Set ActSht = Sheets("Plan1")
lastRow = ActSht.Cells(ActSht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' Checks last row with data

sheetName = 'mysheet
Set ShtPlan = Sheets("Plan1")

myRange = "'" & sheetName & "'!$A:$P"
myRange2 = "'" & sheetName & "'!$A:$A"

For i = 5 To lastRow Step 7
    lookupFrom = ActSht.Cells(i - 3, 1).Address
    Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=INDEX(" & myRange & "," & "MATCH" & "(" & lookupFrom & "," & myRange2 & "," & "0)+3" & "," & "COLUMN(A1)+3)"
'The formula COLUMN (A1) changes the result accordingly.

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Look into R1C1 formulas and change the third criterion in the Index formula into that format.

Comment: The formula works just right, the thing i'm having trouble is with autofill

Comment: I managed to Autofill right but only on the active cell, what can i change to make it autofill on every variable?
`lngLastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column`

`Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, lngLastColumn)).FillRight`

Comment: I did it, used `Cells(Cells(i, 3)` as a variation on `ActiveCell`